# Tweepy StreamingClient save json to file

Tags: python, json, api, twitter

I'd like to save Tweepy stream tweets to a .txt with json format. According to the [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/streamingclient.html#tweepy.StreamingClient) it should be possible to set `return_type=dict` with StreamingClient.
With the following code I get: `TypeError: Object of type Tweet is not JSON serializable`. Maybe I would need to set the parameter return_type=dict in the superclass? Afte a lot of trying I haven't been able to make it work. I'd be very grateful for any help!

```
import tweepy
import json    
from tweepy import StreamingClient, StreamRule

class TweetPrinter(tweepy.StreamingClient):

    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        with open("fetched_tweets.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(tweet, indent=4))
        return True
            
printer = TweetPrinter(bearer_token=bearer_token, return_type=dict)  # I don't get dict as output.

rule = StreamRule(value="Python")
printer.add_rules(rule)

printer.filter(expansions=['author_id', 'geo.place_id'], tweet_fields="created_at")
```